# Understanding why induction coils accelerate ferro-magnetic substances

Tags: electromagnetism

If I magnetize a ferromagnet in an coil this ferromagnet will get accelerated towards the center of the coil. And even more so, after reaching the center of the coil, the ferromagnet will get decelerated, while some magnetic properties of the ferromagnet remain.

Why does this happen?